# How to run jenkins with HTTPS on MacOS

Tags: macos, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a MacOS based Machine, and I am running a Jenkins instance on it. It run with HTTP protocol (http://127.0.0.1:8080). I would like to run it SSL security (https://127.0.0.1:8080).

How to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

I tried running it on 8443 port (127.0.0.1:8443). It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your instance to just be available over https, you can configure that with the startup paramters, e.g.:

```
--httpPort=-1 \
--httpsPort=443 \
--httpsKeyStore=path/to/keystore \
--httpsKeyStorePassword=keystorePassword
```

The keystore is a Java keystore with your certificate - if you need one, you can use let's encrypt or a self signed one.

For a bigger instance, I would recommend a reverse proxy in front of Jenkins. The documentation how to do this can be found here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-with-jenkins/

Comment: hi @S.Spieker, where do I need to add these parameters? in MacOS directory structure? Can you pls let me know.

Comment: I think you can edit the startup command - if installed via brew - with `sudo nano /usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist`